# Craft CMS 3 - Always load "en" translation file

Tags: craft3, localization

I have 2 sites (fr and en), fr is default.

In `index.php`, I have `define('CRAFT_SITE', 'fr')` and `define('CRAFT_SITE', 'en')`

In templates, I'm using `{{ 'Texte FR'|t }}` tag.

In `/craft/translations/en/site.php`, I have my translation : `'Texte FR' => 'Text EN'`

When I test the English version, it's OK.

When I test the French version, English translations are displayed.

If I remove translations folder, of course, it's OK.

If I add 'fr' folder in translations, Englishis  still displayed.

Is there a way to trace the choice of the translation file by Craft?

I can't find why ...

Thank for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Craft 3 the setup works a little bit different from the Craft 2 setup. You don't actually have to make changes to your `index.php` to switch the languages.

The languages are defined on a Site base. The translation folder now lives in the root of your projects: `projectFolder/translations/fr/site.php`.

As of Craft 3.1, you can set the Base Url of each site to a variable in your `.env` file and use that variable in the admin panel with the site setup. `@web` as your Base URL doesn't work to properly detect what site you are on.

So in your case, make two sites in the admin panel. Make two variables in your `.env` file:

```
SITE_URL_FR = '...'fr/'
SITE_URL_EN = '.../en/'
```

Use those variables to set your Base Url in the sites config. You can target them with `$SITE_URL_FR`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @Jan_dh

I've remove "/www/fr" and "/www/en" folders
I've add SITE_URL_FR and SITE_URL_EN in .env file
I've change my sites config with this new env variables
It's easier to manage now

But, frontend still load english translation in the french environnement

Comment: Are you on Craft 3.1?

Comment: Does the folders you made in the translations also match the language handles of the site?

Comment: Craft CMS 3.1.3 - Yes, "/craftfolder/translations/en/site.php"

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but when you visit your site, if you have have another tab opened and you're logged in as a user with english set as your main language, it might be taking over your frontend language maybe..? Not able to test but this came to mind when I read your issue :)

Comment: @Olivier Bon - No, same problem. Logged out, devMode false, ... strange because i've got other website without problem. ??..

Comment: Cleared your cache?

Comment: Yes cache clear. I think there is an error during install

Comment: Hey, Craft 3.1.4 was available. After the update, everything work fine !

Comment: Good news! Glad you got it sorted :)